# vsftpd virtual users home directories with pam-mysql

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, pam, vsftpd

I've seen many solutions like `homedir=/somepath/$USER` where `$USER` takes from sysvar
and I want to change it for every user with mysql database. I'm using it with pam-mysql so it will look like

```
Id login passwd homedirectory
```

And I want this home directory to put in vsftpd.conf->home_directory = *something like*

```
 select homedirectory from vsftpd where login='$USER'
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crap, it's so silly and this works...

```
local_root=``mysql -sN -utestuser -ptestpass -h localhost DB_NAME -e "select homedir from vsftpd.users where userid = '$user'"``
```

Comment: Where did you have found the related documentation?